# How do you wrap a plane around an object?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

I'm fairly new to Blender and I'm trying to make a teddy model and I want to wrap the arms around the body (Like how when you drop cloth on a ball, it forms to the shape of the ball where it lands)

This is what  I have at the moment:

[image]

However, the red arm is a flat plane so when i try to attach it onto the body some of the arm either goes into the body or is too far from it:

[image]

So I need it to be curved to the same curve of the body where it joins on.

I've tried using the shrink wrap modifier but that just makes the hand go deformed and when I get it in the right position it doesn't follow the curve of the body anyway.

I've tried making a curve and manually created points following the curve of the body and using the curve modifier on the arm and setting it to the curve.

I've tried using the simple deform modifier on the arm and selecting curve and curving it however, this just sort of twists it in a weird way.

I've also tried creating a uv sphere (thinking it might be the fact that the body is actually a cube would effect it) and trying the shrink wrap modifier for that but it still has the same effect.

In case it's not clear what i'm trying to do here how it is now from a top view:
[image]
... and here's what I want to achieve:
[image]

The body is a cube that I have used a subdivision modifier on and adjusted (It is not a sphere) and I made the arm by creating a curve, setting the spline type to poly and manually placing each point to form the shape, then converting it too a mesh and filled in the face.

It's probably something really stupid i'm missing but I would be very grateful if you could help.

Thanks,

Saul

Comment: Shrinkwrap works best when there is enough geometry both in the target object and the modified object. Try to add more geometry to your arms so that it can bend. In your case you should set the shrinkwrap method to "project" along the X axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Create a plane, subdivide it, put it between your sphere and the arm.
- Give your plane a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the sphere as the *Target*. Disable the modifier visibility for the moment.
- Give your arm a *Surface Deform* modifier with the plane as the *Target*. Click on the *Bind* button.
- Enable the plane's *Shrinkwrap* visibility.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've used the shrinkwrap modifier on the plane with the sphere as the target and that worked. I've also bound the arm to the sphere using the surface deform modifier but the arm is still flat and hasn't curved. @moonboots

Comment: you need to click on Bind with the plane's modifier visibility off (disable the screen icon in the modifier), then turn it on, did you do that?

Comment: Thank you, this worked :)